# Webclient chunked response status 400 but empty response body

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I'm currently running this usecase :

- calling the same http endpoint x3 times using Spring Weclient with different request body
- I'm using Spring not reactive, so I use .block()
- each call is executed inside a CompletableFuture
- when the responses came back , with a 400 status code , I handle this case inside the completableFuture, test the throwable which is a WebClientResponseException

The issue I'm facing is the response body is empty (sometimes :D)

- the response is marked withTransfer-Encoding: chunked
- I added the netty wiretap to log debug the body (I followed https://www.jvt.me/posts/2022/02/13/log-webflux-client/)
- the wiretap shows a lot of data ... but the body is empty. A bit contrary

Is it possible the response body is not consumed a the Webclient level ? Partially consumed ? due to the chunked data ?

It seems the order is not good like if I was entering the completableFuture.whenComplete too soon.

If anyone has some pointers, thanks

**Update 1**:
Some additional info : https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1477

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> appelHTTP(echange.contexte().refExterne(), fluxInfinoe).get(), executor)
                .whenComplete((apiResponseDto, throwable) -> {
                    AccuseReceptionDonneeInterne accuseReception = Optional.ofNullable(apiResponseDto)
                            .map(reponse -> AccuseReceptionDonneeInterne.succes(fluxInfinoe.numeroDonneeEchangee(), reponse.getMessage()))
                            .orElseGet(() -> {
                                List<ReponseErreurInfinoe> erreurs = conversionErreurInfinoeService.convertir(throwable.getCause(), fluxInfinoe.numeroDonneeEchangee());
                                return AccuseReceptionDonneeInterne.echec(fluxInfinoe.numeroDonneeEchangee(), erreurs);
                            });
                    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new EnvoiInfinoeReponse(accuseReception));
                });
```

When I'm entering `whenComplete` the body is empty (in some cases).
The `appelHTTP` uses the ApiClient generated by OpenApiGenerator:

```
    @Override
protected AppelHttpInfinoe<ApiResponseDto> appelHTTP(String correlationID, FluxInfinoe fluxInfinoe) {
    return () -> {
        OperationsBudgetaires operations = (OperationsBudgetaires) fluxInfinoe.donneeInfinoe().contenu();
        FluxBudgetaireDto dto = FluxBudgetaireModelToDtoMapper.toDto(operations);
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Flux budgetaire DTO : {} ", dto);
        }
        return fluxApi.get().processOperationBudgetaire(xJwtAuthorisation(), correlationID, dto).block();
    };
}
```

And a sample of the wiretap :

```
2023-05-09 16:03:29.386 DEBUG 43487 --- [or-http-epoll-4]
reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [b718bf72-1,
L:/172.16.17.183:53310 - R:anothersite/135.143.33.78:443] READ: 8188B
HTTP/1.1 400 Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Set-Cookie: SERVERID=; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction,apikey
Content-Type: application/json Date: Tue, 09 May 2023 14:03:28 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: Close
```

**Update 2**:

- Switching to another httpConnector like Apache HttpComponents : same issue. Netty : not guilty ! :)
- We tried without CompletableFuture : same thing. Not guilty.
- Webclient or reactor ? not sure.
- multiple parallel small requests seems good
- 3 requests over 1Mo and not small responses : weird behavior
- I'm reading the doc to gain a better understanding. Perhaps it is in our code or configuration. We are just trying to restrict the search perimeter :) any pointers are appreciated

**Update 3**:

- when Webclient receive a 200 but the response is too large for the buffersize an exception is raised with info about increasing the buffersize
- when Webclient receive a 4xx but the response is too large, the exception is swallowed and a empty body is pushed down the next actor

**Update 4**:

End of story. The issue was on the remote server (not managed by me -> not easy to test) :)

Comment: Please provide some code or example application.